# Firebase Notifications register is OK, but ios swift is not receiving notifications (worked properly before upgrade of Xcode to 8.3.2)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently updated to Xcode 8.3.2 and push stopped working; although I did not change anything but only upgraded swift version to current one

In my Firebase console, when I send to all iOS swift devices (I got only one registered) stats shows 0 (screenshot http://joxi.ru/Y2LBBaVH39alr6)

The push token I get is

```
cGH1MCWEvr8:APA91bFxQkydAWsmdyCHEKma-jSn9wS6Ub_bxRCDVR3nFx-9URNLRifeRxS_nnD_kgM5P5J6bH2vQK2e1RwxCi1PzbPrwW7WU2qjQc-KhRVlX6V5VBl3bKzgQgjNnh-C4Y8OgiOcJQpt
```

And this is what I got when sending to certain device (screenshot http://joxi.ru/eAOGGOVuyxOBAo)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in ios 10 new framework  called UserNotifications was introduced you need to try the below code for iOS 10 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
 application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

Comment: @NishantBhindi previously it worked fine on ios swift 10.2, but after I upgraded Xcode to 8.3.2 and swift version to latest one, it stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but to avoid deprecated code for iOS 10+ (Swift 3.1.1 and XCode 8.3.2) this is a sample AppDelegate.swift file to get push notifications working. (Note: In addition to enabling Push Notifications, you must also enable **Remote Notifications** in **Background Modes** under the **Capabilities** menu in your XCode project.)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //create the notificationCenter
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            //FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }
        print("Registration succeeded! Token: ", token)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Registration failed!")
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // Firebase notification received
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
        print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

        let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
        let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let body : String = d["body"] as! String
        let title : String = d["title"] as! String
        print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
        self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: title,message:body,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)

    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
        print("Handle push from background or closed\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    }

    func showAlertAppDelegate(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    // Firebase Code Ends
```

}

For assistance with migrating code to the latest Firebase changes, visit this link:
[Firebase Migration 2017](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide)

I hope this helps or points you in the right direction!

01010011 01010000 01000101 01000011 01010100 01010010 01000101